# Proper use of React getDerivedStateFromProps to control child component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state, lifecycle

I have a bit of a dilemma with React `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle methods. Following is an example and you can find a working [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxkm1w52x5). What I want to do is change the child state from parent (*Turn Off From Parent*) some times.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOn: true
    };

    this.turnOff = this.turnOff.bind(this);
  }

  turnOff(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isOn: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child isOn={this.state.isOn} />
        <p>
          <a href="#" onClick={this.turnOff}>
            Turn Off From Parent
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOn: false
    };

    this.turnOff = this.turnOff.bind(this);
    this.turnOn = this.turnOn.bind(this);
  }

  turnOff(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isOn: false
    });
  }

  turnOn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isOn: true
    });
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.isOn) {
      return { ...state, isOn: true };
    }

    return null;
  }

  render() {
    const toggleState = this.state.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF";
    return (
      <div>
        <p>I am {toggleState}</p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" onClick={this.turnOn}>
            Turn On From Child
          </a>{" "}
          |{" "}
          <a href="#" onClick={this.turnOff}>
            Turn Off From Child
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I did read [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html). However I was wondering if there is a way to solve this without *Fully controlled component* or *Fully uncontrolled component with a key* because the only problem here is `getDerivedStateFromProps` triggers everytime when the local state change, unlike `componentWillReceiveProps` which runs when the parent component renders the child component.

Comment: you want to do this without using `getDerivedStateFromProps` ?

Comment: @Sakhi I don't mind not using `getDerivedStateFromProps` if you have a good way of doing it